# PaperJS trouble creating circle on mouseDown

Tags: javascript, shapes, paperjs

I'm trying to replicate a potter's wheel effect, where a user can click on a piece of the wheel, hold down the mouse, and a circle will be created with respect to the center of the wheel.

Like in this persons demo: https://balazsdavid987.github.io/Pottery-Wheel/

But what's happening for me can be seen here: 
http://p2-paperjs-dpayne5-dpayne589733.codeanyapp.com:3000/coloring/

The relevant pieces of code are the following:

```
var tool = new paper.Tool();


        //array to hold all curves drawn from mousedrags
        var allPaths = [];

        var currPath;
        var rotationPath;

        //wheel center point, @center of canvas
        var wheelCenter = new paper.Point(350,350);

        //create the potters wheel
        var wheel = new paper.Path.Circle({
          center: wheelCenter,
          radius: 300,
          strokeColor: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 5
        });


        //hold down to create a continous curve with respect to wheelCenter
        tool.onMouseDown = function(event) {
          currPath = new paper.Path();
          currPath.strokeColor = cp.history[cp.history.length-1];
          currPath.strokeWidth = 10;

          currPath.add(event.point);

        }


        //creates a curve from the last position to the new position of mouse
        tool.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
          currPath.add(currPath.rotate(4, wheelCenter));

        }


        //add the curve to allPaths, which then gets animated in onFrame
        tool.onMouseUp = function(event) {
          allPaths.push(currPath);
        }


        paper.view.onFrame = function(event) {
          for (var i = 0; i < allPaths.length; i++) {
            allPaths[i].rotate(4, wheelCenter);
          }
          //testPath.rotate(3, wheelCenter);
        }


        paper.view.draw();
```

I'm not understanding why the mouseDrag would make a circle way father out from where my mouse has clicked, and I've been stuck on this for awhile.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from your technical difficulty with the `onMouseDrag` method, I think that you should change your approach to the problem.
The thing is that if you rely on mouse drag event (which is only triggered when the mouse move), you won't be able to paint on the wheel by keeping your mouse static (as shown in your reference demo).
So you would better keep track of the mouse position (by listening to a mouse move event), and draw on each frame, adding the last mouse position to the current path (only when drawing of course).
Better than a thousand words, here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.3/S/fVVLi9swEP4rQy7xQvAubU9ZeigpLXsIXWhLD7t7UKxxLCxLZqTEhCX/vSNbfuS1gRB7Xv4eY+V9ZkSFs+Xsd4k+K2aLWWZluL+/hxWh8Ai+QGgKRJ2+0qvJrHG+u4evYLCBZ+GLdKUo05i8hxLgT4bGIy1hr7BJu5tFnyMh1c4t4fPDwxBznmyJK6stN803WmTl/Cz5T0lfcFeIHu8ew0/4jkAFbMnuagYsGKHSGhisF8qA4OtAY+eQQJJoDNQBdez/UyjXNXChbbgMvIXKEgIKp/QByPooRcWpLfIFTeQIw1yU42fAkJzgezLKM4kwYS9IiY1G13Zr9JDtiFifoOJjHwsQldnyxFxoh0NcC+fXllk8W6e8smb6lF+GIXMOpG1MmrYPyHcmC3VgTdv3nVMJ7vl5dzB4xb1czvjIs4aBwyBOa+UIcOL4aHXrEG4rrmFTX9rpaW2V8W+Lk5oTiwnl/Eo6mvypz0SjI8xvUgJLyeYENzvVW88HsG0sFVKuCqVlMsF+MmgtqIyOCNfLPQwZ5fe069Q/XhO6snu8IfSaUzeELhF5R4k3HGzeEumm1dHTBcf6fdy0OysDY+YEraphOScTw4BIs2XPCHhrswJy4jd74HSxOsxuYtVtkizudYp/6xsEVVUT04caKbdUCZOhg80BHCe0yg9B2t6/a1uW9oXJB54Z6z/wbXxtzjhNlLlg9SOEb3CKB0C3coJXzsjxYIyn3dkSdi3Jl0U8PXt/T0g95dAwHxo85MOmp5UOA1UOSYxOkI3owm4ENMHks23qX5bpiqTTCVPheU5ysSgj3uMgKP9PbPjQLbuFnC1f3o7/AQ==) demonstrating how this can be achieved.

```
// Create the wheel.
const wheel = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 300,
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 3
});

// Create a group that will contain all the user drawn path.
// This will allow us to more easily rotate them together.
const paths = new Group();

// Init state variables.
let currentPath;
let drawing = false;
let lastMousePosition;

// On mouse down...
function onMouseDown(event) {
    // ...start a new path.
    currentPath = new Path({
        segments: [event.point],
        strokeColor: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 2
    });
    // Add it to the paths group.
    paths.addChild(currentPath);
    // Mark state as drawing.
    drawing = true;
}

// On mouse move...
function onMouseMove(event) {
    // ...keep track of the mouse position, this will be used to add points to
    // the current path on each frame.
    lastMousePosition = event.point;
}

// On mouse up...
function onMouseUp(event) {
    // ...improve performances by simplifying the path.
    currentPath.simplify();
    // Mark state as not drawing.
    drawing = false;
}

// On each frame...
function onFrame(event) {
    // ...rotate paths around the wheel center.
    paths.rotate(4, wheel.position);
    // If we are currently drawing...
    if (drawing) {
        // ...add the last mouse position to the current path.
        currentPath.add(lastMousePosition);
    }
}
```